# rsyslogd using 100% CPU Utilization on all RHEL EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, virtual-machine, rhel

Since past two days, rsyslogd is using 100% CPU Utilization on all RHEL EC2 Instances in my environment. I Stopped and started rsyslog service but still issue persists.
This is first time we are facing this kind of behaviour in multiple servers.
There is sufficient disk space/memory exists in all servers.
I checked kernel logs (/var/log/kernel) and server messages( /var/log/messages),but not find any useful info.

Following is the OS and Kernal versions of all servers.

Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.2 (Maipo)
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64

Can someone please suggest on this.

Comment: How much log do you produce by the other application?

Comment: Thanks Tony for response. Log size is below 20 MB for each server. Sadly, for all 200 servers, we are experiencing 100% cpu utilization for rsyslog service. This was never happened before since two years.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question -- and stackoverflow is for programming questions only. You should ask this either in https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is due to cert expiry for rsyslog. Observed a lot of connection retry errors in system messages for all clients. Post renewing certs in rsyslog, cpu went down.

Comment: How can I renew the certs?